# PHP $_GET is not working

Tags: php, get

I have a problem with $_GET when i use $_GET['username'],it says that username is Undefined index.
Here is my code :

```
 echo $_GET['username'];
```

and here is my link that I want to get username : 
`http://localhost/Likefacebook/includes/user/profile.php?username=oussemab98`

Remarque: when I try with another example, it works. I don't know why?

Comment: What does var_dump( $_GET ); output?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: i use var_dumb and it shows array(0){}

Comment: Do you maybe have a mod_rewrite rule that sends the GET hit to another URL without its original parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['username'])) {
var_dump($_GET['username']);
} else {
echo "$_GET username not found";
}
?>
```

Try to type a username in now. Simple file to test if it's the $_GET or the data inside.

Comment: What PHP version are you using?

Comment: php version: 7.1.6

Comment: @MohamedAmineBejaoui What software you using. Apache? Nginx?

Comment: i use Apache server

Comment: LAMP? Xampp? Wamp? Mamp?

Comment: Attempt a reinstall of the software? This is quite unusual. Try on a different directory such as htdocs directly.